# A Couples Of Ambiguities In Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am following a tutorial and I wrote the code below. One thing I dont understand is that why don't we call the html method on the post object? Secondly, from where does the Post function get the path parameter from?

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
import markdown
from werkzeug.utils import cached_property
import os

FILE_EXTENSION = '.md'

app = Flask(__name__)

class Post(object):
 def __init__(self,path):
    self.path = path

 @cached_property
 def html(self):
    with open(self.path,'r') as file_input:
        content = file_input.read().strip()
        return markdown.markdown(content)

@app.route('/')
def index():
   return 'Hello World'

@app.route('/blog/<path:path>')
def post(path):
   path = os.path.join('posts', path + FILE_EXTENSION)
   post = Post(path)
   return render_template('post.html',post = post)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What "html method" are you referring to?  The `Post` class as defined there doesn't have an `html` method.  It looks like you may have an indentation error in your code.

Comment: @BrenBarn I suspect that's a copy/paste error, and the html function (which takes `self` as a parameter) is actually meant to be part of the Post class.

Comment: which tutorial are you following ?

Comment: "Building A Static Blog Generator In Flask by Tuts+"

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you marked the `post()` function with a decorator, telling Flask what URLs to route to that function:

```
@app.route('/blog/<path:path>')
def post(path):
```

See the `<path:path>` element in there? Now anything past the `/blog/` part of the URL is taken and passed to `post()` as the `path` argument, so if you accessed `http://localhost:8000/blog/foo/bar/baz`, then Flask would take the path past `/blog/` and call `post('foo/bar/baz')`. That's where `path` comes from.

It is the responsibility of the *template* to produce the HTML:

```
return render_template('post.html',post = post)
```

This looks up the file `post.html` in your templates directory, and executes it as a Jinja2 template page. It can access the `post` variable because you passed it in. It is that template that does all the HTML work; the template contains a line `{{ post.html|safe }}` to include the result from the `Post.html()` method.

Your `Post` class uses a *cached property* for the `.html()` method. This means two things:

1. it is a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), which means you can *indirectly* invoke the method by treating it as an attribute. `post.html` will look up the attribute on the `post` object, Python will notice it is a [descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) and call the special [`__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) on it, which in turn calls the `Post.html` method.
2. The [Werkzeug `@cached_property` decorator](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/#werkzeug.utils.cached_property) *caches* the result on the instance. It makes use of the difference between class attributes and instance attributes.

   When first looked up, `post.html` is not found on the instance, so Python then turns to the `Post` class. It finds the `html` descriptor there, invokes it, and the `cached_property` descriptor calls the actual `Post.html` method. The *result* of that call is then stored as an instance attribute. After this, *every time* `post.html` is looked up, there is an attribute on the instance itself that can be used.

Comment: Thanks  Can you please tell me what the `@cached_property` decorator does? and why don't we call the `html` method?

Comment: @NaumanAhmad: having found the tutorial project files I think I know what you mean; you are wondering why it uses `{{ post.html|safe }}` and not `{{ post.html()|safe }}`. This is why it is important to include such details, don't make us guess as to what exactly you are puzzled about.

Comment: The name if my template is `post.html` ?

Comment: @NaumanAhmad: sorry, I don't know what that question means. Your template file is called `post.html`, but that's just a filename and extension. *In* that template, there is a tag `{{ post.html|safe }}`, which means: look up the `html` attribute on the object referenced by `post`.

Comment: No, actually what I am asking is that we are converting the Markdown to HTML in the `html` method in the `Post` class. So in order to access the values returned by the `html` method we need to call it using an object. But we are not doing that, so how are we getting the returned value?

Comment: @NaumanAhmad: That's what I explained; `html` is a *property*. `post.html` accesses it as an attribute, Python translates that access to a method call. Methods have `self` passed in automatically; that is bound the `Post` instance, the same object `post` refers to.

Comment: What you are trying to day is that `@property` decorator changes a method to a property?

Comment: Got it, and why do we use it? I mean what is the advantage of using `@property`

Comment: @NaumanAhmad: simplified API, the ability to intercept setting and deleting, and in this specific case, the ability to load the data just *once*, then cache it transparently.